# Sort Groups in Excel by Totals Row

Tags: excel, sorting, subtotal

I've got a table similar to this and I need to figure out how to sort the companies as groups with respect to the numbers in the yellow boxes. Any ideas as to how?
Thanks! [image: Sample Table]

Comment: so, you need the section for `Blu` to be first, `Red` 2nd, `Grn` 3rd (Red and Grn are tied, actually), and `Ylw` 4th?

Comment: Actually, I want them to be sorted backwards, but you get the idea. For tied companies, I'd guess alphabetical works.

Comment: you may need VBA for this. I played around with helper columns, but as soon as I sorted the formulas were destroyed. Maybe I just need to different formulas, but either way its a tricky one.